# Keep hover background image active only unless second button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hover, focus

I have two buttons (each with grey background image), and for each of those a color hover background image.  I'd like to keep the color background active only unless the button next to it is clicked.  Right now if you click anywhere on the screen the focus of that background hover image reverts back to the original grey button/image.

Here's the fiddle with the CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/J6DP9/8/

```
<div class="buttons-holder">
    <button id="rdb1" type="button" name="toggler" value="US">United States</button>
    <button id="rdb2" type="button" name="toggler" value="International">International</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="cms-pages">
    <div class="divclearboth"></div>
    <hr>
</div>
<div id="blk-0" class="toHide">
    <div class="center-form-img">
        <img src="{{media url=" wysiwyg/form-inactive.jpg "}}" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="blk-US" class="toHide" style="display:none;">{{block type=core/template name=wholesale-us template=cmg/wholesale-us.phtml}}</div>
<div id="blk-International" class="toHide" style="display:none;">{{block type=core/template name=wholesale-intl template=cmg/wholesale-intl.phtml}}</div>
```

Here's the JS:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("[name=toggler]").click(function () {
        $('.toHide').hide();
        $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use Jquery click() and css() functions to change the original background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code to add an `active` class to the last clicked `button` and remove the `active` class from all others.

http://jsfiddle.net/J6DP9/16/

Comment: That works great! However, now I'm running into an issue where the forms' captcha is interfering with one another.  Do you have any advice how to disable the form that isn't active?  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: When you say "interfering" I'm not able to get a clear picture of what the problem is exactly. However, I think that you might be able to do something with $('.captcha').prop('disabled', true); to disable all captchas and then enable the active one with $('#blk-' + $(this).val() + ' .captcha').prop('disabled', false);

Comment: I accepted the first answer.  Thanks for the help...obviously I'm still new.  I submitted another post for help with captcha.  I have listed the actual url to the form (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014308/two-forms-on-same-page-each-with-a-captcha-but-they-are-conflicting). If you have some advise, please feel free to keep me posted.  Thanks again!