# Two forms on same page each with a captcha but they are conflicting

Tags: forms, captcha, conflict

I have two forms on the same page...one for people in US and one for people Internationally. The user selects the form by selecting an icon.  I have some javascript to enable the form according to the users choice.  The issue is, that each form has a captcha and they are conflicting with one another.

Currently I have the css set to "display: none;" for the inactive form.  Is there an easy way to avoid this conflict, either with css or javascript?

Here is a look at the current javascript:

```
$(function () {
$("[name=toggler]").click(function () {
    $("[name=toggler]").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.toHide').hide();
    $("#blk-" + $(this).val()).fadeIn(1000);
});
```

});

If you need more, please let me know.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: can you post the HTML code for the two forms?

Comment: here's a link to the working code: http://www.woodzee.com/wholesale-us ...keep in mind, the US form validates fine because its elements come first in the html.  It's the international one that has issues.

Comment: Hey Jim, any idea how I might be able to solve this?  Look forward to hearing back!